# Django package is not getting installed in virtualenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

The many times I am trying to install Django in a virtual environment in Python 3.9. It's showing an OSError and the package is not getting installed.

```
pip3 install django
```

Error:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Users\\Sandip\\Documents\\Projects\\Beta-Ecom\\myenv\\Lib\\site-packages\\sqlparse'
```

[image]

Kindly help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: That is not the image of the code . Thats when I am trying to do pip install django in virtual environment . Its shows an OS error

Comment: the idea is the same, copy the *text* into the question body. Right now it is hard to search the exception, to try to reproduce the error, it is a way to transform data in a "bloated" way, and people with screenreaders can not see this. The meta article describes why posting an image is *not* a good idea.

Comment: Ok! Thanks mate